# TypeORM Custom Repository, select distinct values from specified column

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

In my backend using nestjs + typeorm + postgresql I have a CustomRepository and want to repalce some plain sql queries.

This is what I have

```
const sqlQuery = `SELECT DISTINCT "myColumn" FROM "myTable"`
const sqlRes = await this.query(sqlQuery);
```

I am trying to get something like this

```
this.find({select:["myColumn"]}); // note the missing DISTINCT
```

But this is giving me the complete column but I want just the DISTINCT values.

I found a lot of weird `createQueryBuilder().select(DISTINCT "myColumn" FROM "...... etc...` solutions, which are not really giving my any benefit over my working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
await getManager().createQueryBuilder('entity')
  .select('column')
  .distinct(true)
  .getRawMany();
```

Comment: In this way I loss other columns, do I miss some part?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason getMany or getCount doesn't work for distinct. As 0xCAP said above:

```
await getManager().createQueryBuilder('entity')
  .select('column')
  .distinct(true)
  .getRawMany();
```

If you want to keep other columns (as your question), just use **addSelect** instead of **select**