# how can we check whether a table already exists or not, in typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

`postgresql, typeorm`
how can we check whether a `table` already exists in a database before starting database operations on that `table`?

currently my code is like this, i check whether an item is present in database. But the problem with this approach is that, if its a fresh deployment, and if the `tables` are not present, then an `exception` is thrown.

```
const found = await this.userRepository.findOne(undefined);   //<<< throws exception if tables not already created

if (found === undefined) {
    const item: Items = this.userRepository.create({....});
}
```

so how can we add a check for a table's existance first, before doing database operations on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use raw SQL queries for this, you can get the Entity Manager from the User Repository and run a query to check the information schema. Just replace the following snippet with your SCHEMA_NAME and TABLE_NAME.

```
const tableExists = (
  await this.userRepository.manager.query(
    `SELECT exists (
      SELECT FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE  table_schema = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
        AND    table_name   = 'TABLE_NAME'
        )`,
  )
)[0].exists;
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema).

Comment: thank you @David Borges for this very good answer....can u please help me with how can i get unique entries from a list of items in tables?.. i have some entries in database table.. but there are duplicates... how do i get unique/distinct items with typeorm?... i cant find any mention of distinct/unique items in typeorm documentation

Comment: Hi @Boris, I believe the way to use the distinct clause from PostgreSQL with TypeORM is by using the [QueryBuilder](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder) syntax. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666465/typeorm-queryrunner-select-distinct) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590279/typeorm-custom-repository-select-distinct-values-from-specified-column).

Comment: thank you @David Borges.. u have been very helpful